# NVCC: warning: allowing all exceptions is incompatible with previous function

Tags: c, cuda, warnings, nvcc

I'm trying to actually use -Wall and remove all warnings in my current program. I know this isn't required but it seems like it can't hurt and hasn't proven to be too time consuming.

I'm using sockets to communicate between two programs: one in C++11 (with c sections) and another in CUDA (so NVCC as the compiler). The socket creation is very similar, and in order to prevent warnings I have written lines such as:

```
#include<string.h>
extern char* strcpy(char*,const char*);
```

This forward declaration works great with gcc/g++ to prevent a warning like:

```
source.c:33:4: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strcpy’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration] 
strcpy(saun.sun_path,CUDA_SOCKET_ADDR);

source.c:33:4: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcpy’ [enabled by default]
```

However, the same code on the NVCC program yields another warning:

```
CUDAsource.cuh(26): warning: allowing all exceptions is incompatible with previous function "strcpy"
/usr/include/string.h(129): here
```

Is there another setting I need to set in my makefile? Currently the C side has the following flags:

```
-g -O0 -Wall -std=c99
```

and nvcc has:

```
-g -G
```

Any tips would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is CUDAsource.cuh something you created?  I cannot find anything related to it through Google, StackOverflow, or the NVIDIA forums.

Comment: Yes, as is source.c. The socket was created following this tutorial http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node28.html. The warning is only related to the "extern" line.

Comment: Can you put the contents of the line in your question?

Comment: Sure, though they don't seem particularly relevant. Nothing unusual about strcpy usage. Here's line 33 of source.c. "strcpy(saun.sun_path,CUDA_SOCKET_ADDR);" where CUDA_SOCKET_ADDR is the socket address. For the CUDA header, line 26 is the "extern" declaration above.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this by fiddling around. Can you provide a short complete piece of code, and the command line you are using to compile it, that will reproduce the warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the extern definitions and adding -D_GNU_SOURCE to the compiler flags resolved the issue.